# blank mysql insert into database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hi i created a private sub where the code must insert a mysql command.... and it does but the funnyest part is that the record disapeares from database
it's there but ehn i stop the debbug and start over it is not there , not even in database
why?

```
 Private Sub gravarAtleta()
    Dim sqlStatement = "insert into atl([nome],[morada],[sexo],[datan],[telf],[desporto]) "
    sqlStatement &= "VALUES (@nome, @morada, @sexo, @datan, @telf, @desporto)"

    Using xConn As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        Try
            Dim xComm As New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, xConn)
            With xComm
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNome.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@morada", txtMorada.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", ComboSexo.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@datan", CType(txtDataN.Text, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@telf", txtTelemovel.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@desporto", ComboBox1.Text)
            End With

            xConn.Open()
            xComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            xComm.Dispose()
            Label1.Content = "O atleta " + txtNome.Text + " foi registado!!!"
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Label1.Content = "Falhou a ligação a base de dados!!!"
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Leva if you must insert a mysql command why the SQL Server connection?

Answer (score 1):

Ive modified the code see if it works

```
Private Sub gravarAtleta()

        Dim sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO atl([nome],[morada],[sexo],[datan],[telf],[desporto]) "
        sqlStatement &= "VALUES (@nome, @morada, @sexo, @datan, @telf, @desporto)"

        Using xConn As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
            Using xComm As New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, xConn)
                With xComm
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNome.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@morada", txtMorada.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", ComboSexo.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@datan", CType(txtDataN.Text, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@telf", txtTelemovel.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@desporto", ComboBox1.Text)
                End With
                Try
                    xConn.Open
                    xComm.ExecuteNonQuery
                    Label1.Content = "O atleta " + txtNome.Text + " foi registado!!!"
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    Msgbox (ex.Message)
                    Label1.Content = "Falhou a ligação a base de dados!!!"
                Finally
                    xConn.Close
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: nop the try statement is wrong the cath must be inside try statement

Comment: Sorry, Prince, this won't even compile if you have Option Explicit On since the xcomm dispose command cannot "see" the xcomm object (specifically, you will get xComm is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Answer (score 0):

First, your command creation should be done with a using statement; that way you won't have to have the dispose statement and the object will be disposed even if the database generates and exception. For example:

```
    Using xComm As New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, xConn)
        With xComm
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNome.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@morada", txtMorada.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", ComboSexo.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@datan", CType(txtDataN.Text, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@telf", txtTelemovel.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@desporto", ComboBox1.Text)

             xConn.Open()

            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    End Using
```

Second, are you perhaps including the database in the deployment for your app? I'm not even sure this is possible using MySQL, but we have run into issues like this before where we include a copy of the database (SQLCE, Access) as content in the solution and have it copy to the output directory on build.

This causes great confusion because the changes that were made during previous debug cycles are overwritten by the newly copied database.

Comment: so it means that te insert command work the problem is the release =, means each time i run the project all the files from debug folder will be changed by a new copy from solution directory?